# Trouble understanding class methods

Tags: python

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self,title,author):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} by {}'.format(self.title,self.author)


class Bookcase:
    def __init__(self,books=None):
        self.books = books

    @classmethod
    def create_bookcase(cls,book_list):
        books = []
        for title,author in book_list:
            books.append(Book(title,author))
        return cls(books)
```

Hi everyone. I'm trying to understand how class methods work like in the following case above.

> When we return cls(books), does the __init__ method get called to
>   return an instance of the classes books (cls.books instead of
>   self.books)

or

> does returning cls(books) not have anything to do with using the init
>   method and returning self.books?

Comment: `cls` inside `Bookcase.create_bookcase` is *equivalent* to `Bookase`, so it works the same as `Bookcase(books)`.

Comment: The `__init__` method doesn't actually return an instance of the class, it _takes_ an instance (usually supplied by `object.__new__`, but you can override that) and fills in its properties.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga When you call it as `Bookcase.create_bookcase` it's equivalent, but when you call it on a subclass (or an instance of a subclass, but that's a weird use case), it's not. If that weren't true, the only difference between `classmethod` and `staticmethod` would be that it gave you a slightly shorter way to refer to the class, which wouldn't have been useful enough to add it to the stdlib.

Comment: Meanwhile: Are you interested in how `classmethod` actually works under the covers? That would require explaining descriptors, which I don't want to get into if it's not necessary, so I left it out of my answer.

Comment: @abarnert sure, I don't disagree.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `create_bookcase`, that `cls(books)` does call the `__init__` method.<sup>*</sup>

However, it calls the `__init__` method of `cls`, not the `__init__` method of `Bookcase`.

What's the difference?

```
class StoreBookcase(Bookcase):
    def __init__(self, book_list, backstock=None):
        super().__init__(book_list)
        self.backstock = backstock if backstock else []
```

Now if I call `StoreBookcase.create_bookcase`, when it does that `cls(books)`, that `cls` is `StoreBookcase`.

Of course `StoreBookcase` might want to override `create_bookcase` to take an optional `backstock` parameter. But in cases where there are no extra parameters in the subclass, or when you're happy with the default value, you can just use the base class's `classmethod` like this. So, `classmethod`s can be used to create "alternate constructors" for an entire hierarchy.

---

<sub>* Technically, it calls the `__new__` method; the `__init__` only gets called if `__new__` returns an instance of `cls`, or of course if you explicitly call it. But most classes just use `object.__new__`, which returns an instance of `cls`, so `__init__` gets called.</sub>

Comment: By the way, if anyone can come up with a better example for a useful subclass of `Bookcase`, please let me know…

Comment: what do you mean when you say it calls the __init__ method of the cls and not of Bookcase?, like does the class have its own init apart from a class instance?

Comment: @AaronB Most of my answer is devoted to explaining the difference between the two. What part of it do you not understand, so I can make it clearer?

Comment: also, I thought the new method is used as a constructor for immutable data types, what is its role in this class method?

Comment: I read through your difference explaination between the two but I dont really understand it (Im new to python so I have trouble understanding things)

Comment: @AaronB Well, the reason `__new__` is overridable is mainly so you can create constructors for immutable data types. But `__new__` always exists, and always gets called—whenever you write `Spam()`, that actually returns `Spam.__new__()`. If you don't override `__new__`, you get `object.__new__`, which just constructs an instance of your class and calls its `__init__` method.

Comment: @AaronB Do you know what subclasses are? If not, you probably need to learn that before `classsmethod`. If you call `Bookcase.create_bookcase`, inside that method, `cls = Bookcase`, so there's no difference between `cls(books)` and `Bookcase(books)`. But if you call `StoreBookcase.create_bookcase(book_list)`, inside the method, `cls = StoreBookcase`, so `cls(books)` is different than `Bookcase(books)`.

Comment: @AaronB If you're familiar with other languages and just don't get how the concepts map to Python, it might help if you tell me which (OO) language you know best. For example, for Java developers, it can be a bit confusing that Python's `staticmethod` is like Java's class methods, while Python's `classmethod` is something different.

Comment: @AaronB no, `__new__` is the constructor on *all objects*. `__init__` is *never* a constructor, note, it returns `None`, whereas a constructor would, by definition, return an instance of the class.

Comment: Oh, I understand that now. Essentially though, the __init__ of bookcase does not get called via the class method but the cls's init gets called. But  is'int the cls's init and the bookcase init the same. Also, I think subclasses are classes which inherit from parent classes

Comment: @AaronB If you call it on `Bookcase`, then `cls` is `Bookcase`, so `cls.__init__` and `Bookcase.__init__` are the same. But if you call it on a subclass, they're not the same.

Comment: Alright, now everything makes a lot more sense, I just have one last question. This is a really dumb question from me but did you need to use the super function in your code snippet above or could you have just done StoreBookcase.create_bookcase(book_list) without it by gaining the book_list from the init but not using super

Comment: @AaronB First, if you have any suggestions for improving the answer, so it would be understandable by someone with this question without multiple followups, that would be a huge help.

Comment: @AaronB As for `super`: When you create a subclass, your `__init__` usually needs to call the parent class's `__init__` via `super`. If I didn't do that here, `self.books` would never get set. (Of course I could manually copy the whole implementation of `Bookcase.__init__` into `StoreBookcase.__init__`, and in this case it's simple enough that you can get away with it, but in general that's a bad idea.) If you still don't understand the use of `super().__init__`, start a new question on that.